# Bonnet (hood) alignment problem

Tags: alignment, peugeot, hood

Yesterday, I made a mistake when I was jacking up my car. The bonnet was open vertically and I didn't notice it is close to the ceiling. I jacked up the car slowly and saw some white material is falling down! It was chalk of the ceiling. Upon close inspection, I discovered the bonnet had penetrated about 10 millimeters into the ceiling but not stuck. I lowered and inspected the bonnet and didn't see any sign of damage but when I closed the bonnet, it didn't align perfectly with the lines of right and left fenders. Now, bonnet seems to sit a bit higher than before. Is there anything I can do about it or should replace the bonnet? I haven't adjusted any bonnet before.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the bonnet now has a greater curve front to back? Pressure from above could have caused the center to bend. If that's true, hinge adjustment may not improve the situation.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - So, what is the solution?

Comment: If it has been curved by compression, the opposite of that is extension. Stretch it back out. Probably not so easily accomplished, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the bonnet hinges - you may be lucky with the holes having enough play.

Comment: Be sure to mark the location of the hinge attachment points BEFORE you loosen any fasteners.  It's easy to get things really off and that will help you get back to the starting point if needed.

Comment: @jwh20 - I don't think I can do anything to improve it. I think I should replace all the hinges and the bonnet and if necessary some other parts too. I wonder what people do when their hoods damage during an accident!

Comment: The quickest way to mark the location of the hinge attachment points is to simply hit it with a very light coat of spray paint. That said, many cars are dirty enough to have the spots already marked!